# Debugging Laravel Octane (Swoole serving) by Yasd -

Tags: laravel, docker, remote-debugging, laravel-sail, swoole

I try to debugging swoole Laravel app with Yasd. I'm getting errors when starting this repo
https://github.com/DenisPetrov100/Laravel-CRUD-SPA-SAMPLE-3

```
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:19:44,403 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:19:44,405 INFO supervisord started with pid 16
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:19:45,407 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 17
laravel.test_1  | Invalid address/ Address not supported: Inappropriate ioctl for device
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:19:45,460 INFO exited: php (exit status 1; not expected)
```

If I use real ip of my host system instead of `host.docker.internal` setting `yasd.remote_host="192.168.65.2"` in `docker\8.1\yasd.ini` and switch on debugging in VScode, then I get stacked container with this lines

```
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:51:13,078 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:51:13,081 INFO supervisord started with pid 16
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:51:14,084 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 17
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:51:15,086 INFO success: php entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

And in case switching off debugging

```
laravel.test_1  | [yasd] recv command error, connection closed
laravel.test_1  | 2022-06-24 10:55:04,720 INFO exited: php (exit status 0; expected)
```

My dev environment:
Windows 10, WSL 2, Docker Desktop for Windows shared with WSL.
docker-compose.yml and DockerFile is from `sail artisan sail:publish`

VS Code extension - PHP Debug
launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for YASD",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```